# What do the phrases 'Mean bugs' and 'Buggy bugs' mean in the picture? Or how should I understand them?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of the phrases 'Mean bugs' and 'Buggy bugs' mean respectively in the picture below?

I can understand all of them separately. But once they are put together, I am not able to understand them. I have googled the two phrases, but can't find an answer.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is "mean" in the sense of unkind or unfriendly.  "Buggy" is just the adjective form of "bug", so "buggy bugs" are typical or exemplary bugs -- bugs with a clear and obvious bug-like nature.

Answer (score 2):

The **mean bugs** are *mean* because they are chasing the little girl (presumably to sting her, perhaps). They are mean because mean can mean “cruel” or “unkind" or “unfriendly”.

The **buggy bug** is *buggy* because he is in the boy’s hair. To “bug” someone is to bother or irk that person, so “buggy” can be defined as “bothersome” or “annoying.”